# Random OG Image Tag Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

Hello I want to have random og Image every time my link is shared in facebook. Like this  [website every time it's scrapped new image is found.Will be great if you can](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=f-u-t-b-o-l.com) help me :) .

Comment: Share a unique URL each time. Facebook caches OG image tags per URL

Comment: No  I want to display random image for same link for my homepage website .Like that of this website https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=f-u-t-b-o-l.com .

Comment: If i really knew what they did I would not have asked the question :(

Comment: Hi Bishal!
Did you already solve this? I am almost eat 1 week just to solve this haha!

Comment: I'm trying to solve this too, nothing seems to work, Facebook keeps caching everything and then it always returns the same image.

Comment: Do you have any status update on this problem?

Comment: I know it's been a while but the problem will be getting FB to see the random images.
It would require a SCRAPE AGAIN on Facebooks debug app.